# What is an HMAC_CTX? What does CTX stand for?

Tags: openssl

I'm reading the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html). The first mention on that page of HMAC_CTX is:

> `HMAC_CTX_init()` initialises a HMAC_CTX before first use. It must be called.

But it doesn't seem to say what an HMAC_CTX. So, what is it, and what does CTX stand for?

Comment: context is normally what ctx stands for im not sure if this follows in your above context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does CTX stand for?

As Luke said, its a context.

---

> What is an HMAC_CTX?

The context is a "scratch pad" area to operate an HMAC. The context will hold state data and intermediate calculations.

Here's the members of the structure from `<openssl src>/crypto/hmac/hmac.h`:

```
typedef struct hmac_ctx_st
    {
    const EVP_MD *md;
    EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx;
    EVP_MD_CTX i_ctx;
    EVP_MD_CTX o_ctx;
    unsigned int key_length;
    unsigned char key[HMAC_MAX_MD_CBLOCK];
    } HMAC_CTX;
```

OpenSSL has other contexts too, like a `PKEY` and `BIGNUM` contexts.